# What JavaScript library does neo4j use to visualizer results in the browser?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

What JavaScript library does neo4j use to visualizer results in the browser?

[image: Neo4J Admin]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Neo4j 2.0 browser uses d3.js (http://www.d3js.org) library to visualize graphs from the results of your Cypher queries.

Comment: There is a GitHub repo which seems to contain the code for it: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/tree/master/src/browser/modules/D3Visualization